# Mount share on windows, from linux through winexe

Tags: linux, windows, mount, samba

Answer has to use winexe.

I'm using winexe (on linux) to mount a samba share on a remote windows 7 with the following command:

```
./bin/winexe -U <user>%<password> //<ip> "cmd.exe /c net use x: \\<ip>\share <password> /user:<user>"
```

This gives me:

```
System error 67 has occurred. The network name cannot be found.
```

But when I do this:

```
./bin/winexe -U <user>%<password> //<ip> "cmd.exe"
```

And then continue to enter in the commandline prompt i'm given on my linux machine

```
"net use x: \\<ip>\share <password> /user:<user>""
```

It works just fine. How can I get this to work on one line like my first command?

Comment: Perhaps your \ chars need to be escaped?  ie \\\\srv\\share

Comment: Good point, I'll try that when i get the chance and let you know if it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Zoredache chars `\` needed to be escaped.

The correct command should be:

```
./bin/winexe -U <username>%<password> //<ip> "cmd.exe /c net use x: \\\\<ip>\\share    /user:<user> <password>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this in linux

```
mount -t cifs -o username=your_name,password=your_pass //192.168.1.1/shared_path /mnt/mount_point
```

Comment: I'm not trying to mount a share on linux, I'm trying to mount it on windows7 through winexe.